# Check for value in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c++, iso

I have an NSMutableArray in my class containing Ingredient objects. I want to check whether the **name** property of any of the ingredients matches a string, but I can't get the syntax quite right.

I'm really missing Linq and predictates.

```
-(BOOL) hasIngredient:(NSString *)ingredientName{
    for (Ingredient *ingredient in ingredients) {
        //if([ingredient isKindOfClass:[Ingredient class]]){
            if ([ingredient->name isEqualToString:ingredientName]) {
                return YES;
            }
        //}
    }
                 return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foo->bar` syntax directly accesses instance variables. You shouldn't do that. The syntax to access a property is:

```
object.property
```

or:

```
[object property]
```

Accessing a property is always a method call. If you have a property `foo` and do `@synthesize foo;`, the compiler generates a method named `foo` and `setFoo:` (if the property isn't readonly).

So you should have something like:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSString *name;
```

Replace `readonly` with `copy` if you want the name to be changeable (the reason to use `copy` instead of `retain` is because you could pass a mutable string and then later modify that mutable string, which would sure yield unexpected results; you avoid that by copying).

Now your method becomes:

```
-(BOOL) hasIngredient:(NSString *)ingredientName{
    for (Ingredient *ingredient in ingredients) {
        if ([[ingredient name] isEqual:ingredientName]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Instead of `[ingredient name]` you can also write `ingredient.name` here, but I personally like the former better since the later is also used for accessing members of a struct which is "cheap" whereas accessing a property always involves a method call and thus is "more expensive". But that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ([ingredient->name isEqualToString:ingredientName])
```

to

```
if ([ingredient.name isEqualToString:ingredientName])
```